# Weird behavior with java, hibernate.initialize()

Tags: java, hibernate

I am noticing a weird behavior when I perform some basic checks using objects that have been .initialize()'ed using Hibernate.

The following 'if condition' fails even when it is supposed to pass:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < trcList.size(); j++)
        {
            if (trcList.get(j).getABC().getId() == abc.getId())
            {                   
                //do something
                break;
            }
        }
```

However if I change it slightly, it passes where expected. In the snippet below, I grab the LHS value in a local variable and use that for comparison:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < trcList.size(); j++)
        {
            int x = trcList.get(j).getABC().getId();
            if (x == abc.getId())
            {                   
                //do something
                break;
            }
        }
```

trcList is an ArrayList created from an array of objects grabbed from a database using hibernate. Various fields in those objects including 'ABC' have been Hibernate.initialize()'ed.

```
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.initializeHibernateConnection(session);
        Criteria cr = ... //specify search criteria

        List results = cr.list();
        TRC[] trcArray = new TRC[results.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            trcArray[i] = (TRC) results.get(i);

            if (trcArray[i].getABC() != null)
            {
                Hibernate.initialize(trcArray[i].getABC());
            }
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return trcArray;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
```

Comment: What does the method `getID()` return?

Comment: getId() returns the row id (primary key) from the table (an integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `trcList.get(j).getABC().getId()` is `java.lang.Integer` and hence it should be compared with `equals()`

```
if (trcList.get(j).getABC().getId().equals(abc.getId())) {

}
```

Below test will assert the same

```
Integer i = new Integer(1); //set to 1
Integer j = new Integer(1); //also set to 1

System.out.println(i == j); //false, because it is reference comparison
System.out.println(i.equals(j)); //true
```